# Manipular key de uma array?

Tags: php, ajax, array, query

Preciso manipular uma `key` que é passa como parâmetro nesta `query`:

```
$Read->FullRead("SELECT DISTINCT ".DB_CONTAS." WHERE 
                 contas_status = 1 `{$FilterAdd} ", "{$FilterValues}");`
```

O `var_dump` `{$FilterAdd}` retorna isso:

```
array (size=3)
  'contastipodetalhe' => string '1' (length=1)
  'anobase' => string '2016' (length=4)
  'mesbase' => string '12' (length=2)
```

***Bom, o que há de complicado nisso?***

Eu preciso que, se o usuário selecionar 1 ou mais campos do filtro, que minha `array` receba apenas os campos que foram selecionados e se algum desses campos for `anobase` *e/ou* `mesbase`, eu tenho que inserir um `year` e `month` na `select` para extrair o **ano** e **mês** para assim poder comparar com o valor selecionado no campo.

***Exemplo:***

Minha `query` atual fica assim:

```
SELECT DISTINCT contas 
 WHERE contas_status = 1 AND 
       contastipodetalhe = :contastipodetalhe AND 
       anobase = :anobase AND mesbase = :mesbase '
```

Eu preciso que ela fique assim:

```
SELECT DISTINCT contas 
 WHERE contas_status = 1 AND 
       contastipodetalhe = :contastipodetalhe AND 
       year(anobase) = :anobase AND month(mesbase) = :mesbase '
```

Note que utilizo `year` e `month`, isso eu não estou conseguindo enviar no vetor neste momento que ele monta o `{$FilterAdd}`:

```
if ($TranspFilter):     
    foreach ($TranspFilter as $fKey => $fValue):     
           $FilterAdd .= " AND {$fKey} = :{$fKey}";     
    endforeach;
    $_SESSION['transp_filter'] = null;
endif;
```

Já pensei em fazer um `if` pra saber se o valor selecionado é **mês** ou **ano** e aí tentar alterar a `key` do `vetor`, mas não rolou, se alguém souber onde eu errei ou me dar outra solução eu agradeço:

```
if ($TranspFilter):     
    foreach ($TranspFilter as $fKey => $fValue):
      if($fKey['anobase']):
          $FilterAdd .= "AND year({$fKey}) = :({$fKey})";
      endif;
      if($fKey['mesbase']):
          $FilterAdd .= "AND month({$fKey}) = :({$fKey})";
      endif;     
      $FilterAdd .= " AND {$fKey} = :{$fKey}";     
    endforeach;
    $_SESSION['transp_filter'] = null;
endif;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu código está incorreto. Você está tratando a chave(string) como se fosse um array.

Corrigindo:

```
if ($TranspFilter) {

    foreach ($TranspFilter as $fKey => $fValue) {
        if ($fKey == 'anobase') {
            $FilterAdd .= "AND year({$fKey}) = :({$fKey})";
        } else if ($fKey == 'mesbase') {
            $FilterAdd .= "AND month({$fKey}) = :({$fKey})";
        } else {
            $FilterAdd .= " AND {$fKey} = :{$fKey}";
        }
    }
    $_SESSION['transp_filter'] = null;

}
```

PS: Reescrevi os blocos do jeito convencional, já que não há nenhum bloco de HTML e não acho que vale apena perder a legibilidade do código escrito dessa forma à toa.

Comment: quase......
após aplicar seu código, duplicou as querys, veja o resultado:

'SELECT DISTINCT contas WHERE contas_status = 1  AND contastipodetalhe = :contastipodetalhe AND year(anobase) = :(anobase) AND anobase = :anobase AND month(mesbase) = :(mesbase) AND mesbase = :mesbase '

Note que apareceu 2 vezes o year(anobase) e month(mesbase)

Comment: Corrigido. Faltou um 'else'.

Comment: deu certo. obrigado